# Как правильно объявить метод

Tags: java, android

Я взял за основу пример из [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) убрал все лишние, немножко переделал и теперь просто хочу повторно использовать галерею в проекте. Галерея берет фотки из файла Constants.java.

```
 public class Constants{

    private static String[] image1= new String[] {
            // Heavy images
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg"
        };

    private static String[] image2= new String[] {
            // Heavy images
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg",
            "https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1440x900/2/96/art-sono-devushki-shkolnicy.jpg"
    };

    public static String[] IMAGES;
    public static String data = "Metal";

static {
    switch (data) {
        case "Metal":
            IMAGES = Metal;
            break;
        case "Marketing":
            IMAGES = Marketing;
            break;
    }

    private Constants() {}

    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }

    public static class Extra {
        public static final String FRAGMENT_INDEX = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.FRAGMENT_INDEX";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }
}
```

Как мне в переменную `data` запихнуть переменную из другой активности?

Например чтоб при старте активности в `data` помешалось `"Metal"`.

```
...
public void btnClick (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Metal.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.Extra.FRAGMENT_INDEX, ImageGridFragment.INDEX);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
...
```

Пробовал через `Intent`, но чет не получилось. Скорей всего из-за того, что в Constants.java не объявлено не одного метода. А как его правильно объявить, чтоб все работа я не знаю.

Comment: Разберитесь все же, чем статические поля и методы отличаются от нестатических.  Иначе вы зададите и третий вопрос с такой же вводной.

Answer (score 2):

Не понятно, что вы именно хотите добится.
Но все же)

```
...
public void btnClick (View view) {
        //Можно тут
        Constants.data = "Metal";
        //
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Metal.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.Extra.FRAGMENT_INDEX, ImageGridFragment.INDEX);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
...
```

Вообще у вас переменная data - помечена как public static. Т.е. она видна ВСЕМ классам. И менять её могут ВСЕ классы.

Comment: Все, спасибо! Разобрался! Надеюсь больше не буду глупых вопросов задавать)

Comment: Окей. Не за что